# How can a graduate student most efficiently become an expert at his research topic?

Tags: graduate-school

Taught courses typically do not reach research level, so there is a significant gap in knowledge that has to be bridged by a graduate student in order to make meaningful contributions to their field. What is the most efficient way to bridge this gap? I could come up with the following possibilities:

1. Find advanced textbooks, prove all the theorems [if maths] and do all the exercises yourself.
2. Organize seminars with other graduate students with related interests
3. Go to conferences or talks given by staff about their research

Is this list exhaustive or is there anything I missed? Which methods of learning are recommended in which situations?

For definiteness, by 'expert' I mean the level necessary to understand current research articles and (in principle) independently reproduce the calculations/proofs.

Comment: What is your working definition of an "expert?"  It is hard to describe a path to an outcome that is ambiguously defined.

Comment: @BrianP: While your comment is true, I feel like it is somehow misleading.  "How to most efficiently become an expert at your research topic?" is a question that takes one's whole graduate career to satisfactorily answer.  It's fair to say that *part* of this is to learn to appreciate and unambiguously define the question.  Fair but maybe not that helpful.  I think a more honest answer is: "This is one of the big questions of your graduate career.  You should keep it in mind, but it will take time to answer.  Getting help on this is one of the main functions of your thesis advisor."

Comment: I agree with Brian P.  One huge distinction: would you like to be an academic expert or a professional expert?

Comment: @Dave: I'm not sure I understand your comment: could you give an example?  In some fields there is a pure/applied distinction, but I view this as part of the choice of the research topic itself and not really the kind of expertise.  But even that distinction is not always applicable.  In many fields, I can't see any difference at all.  What would it mean to be a "professional expert" in Galois cohomology or logical positivism or....?

Comment: Here's a(n obviously strictly optional) thought experiment: let me go back in time to when I was a graduate student.  Suppose I asked you how to most efficiently become an expert in the field of quaternionic Shimura varieties.  What questions will you ask about my working definition of expert or academic versus professional in order to usefully answer my question?  I honestly can't think of anything useful to say along these lines, and this is years after my actually having become an expert on this research topic.

Comment: Pete, sounds to me like you understand my comment perfectly!

Answer (score 13):

For most disciplines, advanced textbooks still provide, albeit necessary, foundations. Conferences allows you to hear what is new and is as such a good way to know where fields are going. I am not sure what you mean by seminars but discussing new papers and topics is always a good way to advance knowledge. But, the major point is to read up on published papers and to focus on the topic of your thesis. The point of research is to advance knowledge and this means you will, or at least have a chance to, be an expert on the field you are researching. So in my view none of the activities 1-3, or combinations, make you an expert, only your own sweat over publications and own work will do so.

Comment: +10 There's no shortcut to reading the papers.

Comment: _For most disciplines, advanced textbooks still provide, albeit necessary, foundations._ — [citation needed] — Or maybe my field is just weird.

Comment: In some cases, the textbooks really do extend all the way to current (or at least very close to it) research.  For examples (from my own area), the book Representations of Algebraic Groups by Jantzen will not need much supplement before one can do research. Same goes for Modular Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type by Humphreys (though calling that a textbook might be a stretch).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this one is fairly easy.  You read, read, and read.  And when you're done, you read some more.

My thesis was a study of two specific products/types of databases.  Of course, the widely-known "Brewer's CAP Theorem" was a core focal point, so I read Dr. Brewer's paper "Harvest, Yield, and Scalable Tolerant Systems."  I then read the paper that analyzed his paper, which (of course) led me to another.  And another.

I went to Amazon.com and looked for books about the non-relational database I was focusing on, and found five.  I bought (and read) all of them.  I looked at the sources for those works, and read more and more.

I went to a conference in Chicago put on by the software company which created my non-relational database of focus.  I talked with the people who created it, as well as with others who used it.  I took lots of notes, looked through many Powerpoint projects, and followed the sources listed in those as well.

This went on for more than a year.

Fast-forward to now, I (successfully) defended my thesis 11 months ago.  Since then, I have taken a new job (that I was recruited for) as a lead engineer, driving big data projects.  I don't really consider myself an expert, but it is apparent that I understand that material (and database theory in general) better than anyone else in our company.

So again, read as much as you can find on your topic.  Question it.  If you have the means, run some of the experiments on your own.  And after that, keep reading.

Comment: "The answer to this one is fairly easy. You read, read, and read. And when you're done, you read some more."  Well, yes.  That was easy to say, and moreover I think it's correct.  It is less easy, however, *to do*.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other informative comments and answers, there is a point that appears to me widely overlooked, namely, that it is hard to rush "maturity" or "experience". Yes, one can speed up "experience_s_", but only to a point, since too much so reduces comprehension of them.

In different words, in addition to accumulation, and assimilation, of many, many factoids and ideas, there are ... intangibles, "intuition", all those vague things.

That is, apart from having seen and remembered many facts, genuine experts have so-well assimilated them, have so-well changed themselves to adapt to a subtler viewpoint, that they have "sense" about otherwise-vague situations.

Yes, I am obviously noting that live mathematics is not formal. It is only that the contemporary writing style has various formal/logistic pretensions, not that the *practice* is that.

As a corollary, I think it is simply not feasible to "become an expert" in grad school, or soon, or... although one must be *wanting* that to exert sufficient energy to move in the right *direction*.

(And, as at other locales, I am not a fan of "routine exercises", unless one has nothing better to do. I think "memorization of proofs" is not nearly as good as "trying to see why the proof _has_to_be_this_, but perhaps getting the thing into one's head by "memorization" is better than not having it in one's head at all.)